# How can I store and update multiple values in React useState? if one of the value is in array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, multiple-input

I have a series of user data elements that I'm collecting inside a React component using single useState Hook.

```
 const [allValues, setAllValues] = useState<IProduct>({
    title: '',
    name: '',
    category: '',
    price: 0,
    image: '',
    size: [],
    color: [],
    inStock: true,
  });
```

we can see two of them is array.

```
 const changeHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setAllValues({ ...allValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    console.log(allValues);
  };
```

and the input box are like these... what are the changes i should make?

```
 <input
        type='text'
        className='form-control'
        id='name'
        name='name'
        placeholder='Enter a Name'
        onChange={changeHandler}
        />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
setAllValues({
 ...allValues,
 toUpdate: newValue
});
```

Is different from

```
setAllValues(prev => ({
 ...prev, 
  toUpdate: newValue
}));
```

Hope it helps